# SpamAssassin REGEX to catch long URL

Tags: regex, spamassassin

I am sharpening my SpamAssassin filter on CentOS. After I got out *.link and .eu domains I like to flag very long domain strings with over 100 characters.

The conditions are:

- Start with http or https
- May or may not contain www
- Ends with EOL, Line break, space, ", ', <

I came up with this one:

```
body     LONG_URL    (https?:\/\/)[^,;\"\'<\s$]{100,}
describe LONG_URL    URL with over 100 characters
score    LONG_URL    0.5
```

It works in the REGEX tester, but doesn't work in SpamAssassin

Comment: Are you sure you want dollar sign to oe in the excluded class? It's not very common in URLs but that seems like an odd reason to pick this particular character to exclude.

Answer (score 3):

You want to write a [`uri` test](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SpamAssassin/SpamAssassin_Rules#URI_Tests), not a `body` test.

Comment: Doesn't URi works only if the URL has www in it? But since mine ain't working I will try it anyway.

Comment: It seems URi can only URLs that are wrapped in HTML.

Comment: Correction:  It seems URi does not work with .LINK TLDs. Exactly the same rules works well with .EU TLDs. My URi EU TLD rule works with or without HTML.

Comment: @yello you are correct, SA doesn't currently support .link or others in the most recent round of TLDs.  That fix is coming soon.  This *only* affects plain-text links in the body; SA will capture .link domains in HTML just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To work around the new TLD issue, you do indeed need a body rule.  As you've written it above, there are some syntax issues and some unnecessary computational costs.  Try this instead:

```
body     YELLO_LONG_BODY_URL  m@\bhttps?://[^\"\'<\s$]{100}@i
describe YELLO_LONG_BODY_URL  100+ char URL, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26919318
score    YELLO_LONG_BODY_URL  0.1
```

That will technically work, though I'm sure you'll find it fires on a LOT of non-spam, marketing mail in particular, especially if you keep that bound at 100 characters (that's small!).  I took out the comma & semi-colon as those could be parts of URLs and a legitimate message would only have its URLs lengths as one character too long, so you're probably fine with just `m@\bhttps?://\S{100}@i`

Warning: I fight spam for a living and have *lots* of data at my fingertips.  You'll hit more non-spam ("ham") than spam under 128 characters.  No size range is going to have a terribly good spam:ham ratio; an [S/O](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/HitFrequencies#The_S.2FO_Ratio), aka [precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall), of 0.900 is possibly acceptable, but you really want to be closer to 1.000.  By my tests, the best range is 192-256 characters, but even that is too weak (S/O = 0.862) to be terribly useful.  There is almost no spam using a link with over 1024 characters (S/O = 0.057).

I changed this rule's name.  It's good to take credit for your rules so that they can be easily identified as yours (rather than upstream SpamAssassin's) when something goes wrong and "credit" becomes "blame"  ... I even linked this answer in the rule description so your users can learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. In the meantime the issue seems to be gone. Seems that spammers try something for a while, and try something else when the delete rate get's too high. What made a big change for me was adding postgrey (grey listing). Highly reccomeded! wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postgrey